# Storing Text in a Semi-Searchable but Compact Format

Tags: database-design, search, text, compression, n-gram

I would like to pull the [Google N-Gram datasets](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets) for use on some commodity hardware. The problem is that these small servers can't handle the size of the data that needs to be stored.

This started me thinking about how other large text based system such as WordNET or search engines handle this problem. **I wonder if there is a way to normalize the data, yet still enable it to be a searchable format?**

Back to the N-Grams, my idea is to store all the words from 1-Gram in the database along with an ID. Then use that ID to create relations in the +2 Gram chains the same way as you would track friend relations in a social network - two ids as the row.

```
TABLE Words
{
    id
    word
}

TABLE TWOGRAM
{
    first_word_id
    second_word_id
}

TABLE THREEGRAM
{
    first_word_id
    second_word_id
    third_word_id
}

TABLE FOURGRAM
{
    first_word_id
    second_word_id
    third_word_id
    forth_word_id
}
```

**Is there a more efficient way to store all this data in a compact way?**

Perhaps instead of compressing the text, hashing could be done against pairs (or sequences) of words to achieve a smaller storage size while still being searchable in the same way passwords are.

Comment: Google lists 360 billion 1grams, but you're only going to store one row for each unique English word. Is that right?

Comment: @Catcall, yes. Rather than storing 360 billion 1grams over and over for each pair or 2+ grouping - Storing the words once - and then using smaller integers to represent the words seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to handle this situation is to chunk your data into small blocks (such as a 2K lines for example), groups datas within blocks by columns, and then compress the transformed block using a fast compression algorithm.
The saving can be pretty significant.

[Edit] With a bit more details, as requested :
The objective here is to handle small compressed data blocks, so keeping memory requirement at reasonable level is necessary. "reasonable" depends on your target system, so that's why it could be 256 lines, or 2K, or 8K.

Each line however has several fields in it.
So compressing directly will not bring significant savings (for example, zip is "only" x5).
Fortunately, the separation character between those fields is well known (0x09), so the start and ending of each field can be retrieved.

The idea is to group all "Fields 1" together, followed by "Fields 2", then "Fields 3", and so on. If the block extracted from the .csv file is 2K lines, we know we have 2K fields of each type.

Then, a simple fast compression algorithm will make wonders on this transformed structure. Correlations are very strong, since consecutive fields tend to have a lot in common. 10x compression ratio is unsurprising for such data. Google N-Gram datasets is likely to be even more favorable.

Since your objective is to hold as much data as possible into memory to search into it, it's recommended to keep each block small enough (roughly between 256 and 8K), and use a very fast compression/decompression algorithm. This way, decompression will be fast enough to become an insignificant part of your algorithm.
For example, something like LZ4 provides about ~1GB/s of decompression speed.

Regarding searching : 
it all depends on what you want to search, but if it is about finding a precise N-gram, then we get lucky, since they are already sorted in lexicographically order.

At this stage, it is enough to store the first N-gram of each block into a table.
When searching a particular N-gram, it is just necessary to find into which block it is.
The first N-gram of the block is necessarily <=. The N gram of the next block is necessarily >. Decompressing the block, as seen above, should be an insignificant part of the algorithm.

Even with blocks of 2K lines, you may have a lot of "header N-gram" to store, so a trivial bubble search can be quite long. A tree or pivot search is recommended.

Once the block is loaded, it is still necessary to search into it to find the proper N-gram. The same tactic as before can be used (load the N-grams into a table, and pivot search into it).

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Are you talking about 2,000 lines of words, or word groupings? Also, how is this still searchable without having to compress each 2k grouping to search it?

Comment: Well, ok for the storing and searching. But i guess that the column/row transformation can cost quite some CPU cycles too.

Comment: @Attract I'm still not following you. When you say "field 1" or "field 2" are you talking about the CSV field columns? If so, do you mean to store each CSV as a single row in the database and decompress it on the fly? If so, that doesn't sound like a good idea since the CSV's are over 100MB each. Some of your points sound like good ideas, but you need to add the missing nouns to your text so we know what you are thinking about.

Comment: Yes that's the basic Idea : in effect, transpose the matrix so that column become lines, and compress the transposition. However, do not do it on the entire file : as you say, say are too big. Chunk them into smaller pieces (such as 256KB each), transpose the chunk, and compress it. The inverse operation (decode, transpose, get back the original chunk) can be done on the fly. Compression algorithms are fast enough to not be in the critical path nowadays. As said by Cyan, the transposition algorithm, if badly optimised, could cost more than the compression itself !

Answer (score 0):

> Rather than storing 360 billion 1grams over and over for each pair or
>   2+ grouping - Storing the words once - and then using smaller integers
>   to represent the words seems like a better choice.

(I summarized my estimates below.)

It's hard to say for sure that integers are a better choice here. You need better estimates of how much disk space you need, how much disk space you have, and how much disk space you can afford.

Statistics tell us that the average length of a word in English is 5.1 characters. In your app, that's the same as 5.1 bytes. Average length of two words is about 10.2 bytes; length of two integers is 8 bytes.

There are about 66 million 2grams in file number 71 (chosen at random). At 10.2 bytes per entry, you're looking at about 673 megs for this file. (That assumes you're only going to store the words, and not the counts.)  For 100 2gram files, you should need between 52 and 67 gigs (ignoring indexes). Add 50% for our profound ignorance. 100 gigs will cover the 2grams.

If you store the counts with the words, this file is 1.6 gigs, and 100 of them should be around 160 gigs. So we have a range of 100 to 160 gigs to store the 2grams.

I'll leave estimating the space required by indexes to you.

Integers save 2.2 bytes per word. But storing two integers means you'll always have to do *two* joins to get real data back. (Storing five integers for 5grams means you'll need *five* joins go get real data back.)  Storing the words themselves requires no joins to get real data.

If you're also storing counts, you can save space by storing a foreign key to the ngram instead of using individual words. So you can store

```
ngram_id  ngram_text
--
143564    five pounds
```

in one table, and

```
ngram_id    year    match_count  page_count  volume_count 
--
143564      1999    4            3           3
143564      2000    2            2           1
143564      2001    1            1           1
143564      2002    1            1           1
143564      2003    2            2           2
143564      2004    1            1           1
143564      2005    6            6           5
143564      2006    30           21          17
143564      2007    39           37          26
143564      2008    44           41          28
```

in another.

For that particular 2gram, text takes 11 bytes, and the integer takes 4. Savings of 7 bytes on each of 10 rows, 70 bytes.  Requires *one* join to get real data. For this approach, I'd estimate about 130 gigs for all the 2grams, excluding indexes and table that supplies the foreign keys.

Summary of my estimates of space needed to store 2grams, based on 100 files of 66 million rows. Excludes space for indexes and general storage overhead (which, depending on the dbms, can be substantial.)

```
                           row_len  gigabytes  joins
----------------------------------------------------
words        with counts     163.2      1,077      0
two integers with counts     128.0        845    2-5

words        without counts   10.2         67      0
two integers without counts    8           53    2-5

one integer  with counts      20          132      1
one integer  without counts    4           26 (for completeness, but not really useful)
```

Multi-terabyte drive arrays aren't terribly expensive these days.  Are y'all going to make money on this?

Comment: Very good points, sometimes optimization's aren't worth it. However, let me add some more food for thought. A standard `integer` column in PostgreSQL/MySQL uses 4 bytes. However it's true that it only goes to ~2 billion which isn't enough for all 360B google 1grams. Still, most of that is just noise/misspellings/emoticons as the WordNet and moby projects have only classified 200k english words. So assuming I trimmed the results down to only 2 billion words I could reduce the storage size by perhaps 50%. Searches would also be faster as comparing integers is faster than strings.

Comment: So if I wanted to find all the 2-grams for a given word I would first get the word's id `SELECT id FROM word WHERE word = ?`, and then I could search the 2-grams table for pairs for that word `SELECT * FROM TWOGRAM WHERE first_word_id = ? OR second_word_id = ?`. This would allow the database to do much faster lookups than by string. It could also store more words in memory due to the decreased size of the integers. BTW, I'm certainly going to separate the word statistics like you mention into a second table. Good idea.

Comment: Integers have about a 4 billion range of values. PostgreSQL doesn't have an unsigned integer, but there's no reason you can't use negative numbers. Don't assume integers with up to five joins will be faster than strings with no joins. You need to test it end-to-end.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of 2B signed ints (for PostgreSQL's sake). However, I'm not sure why you mention joins. There are no joins to be performed in the example I gave. Perhaps you have a specific implementation you are thinking of that needs joins...?